# hdfs directory - how to check write access

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I would like to check whether the hdfs directory has write access or not. i can see methods for file is existing or not, but i don't see methods for having write access or not in hdfs file system classes.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
if (fs.exists(new Path(cleanFilePath)) {
      // do something.
}
```

And also, when i try to write some RDD using saveAsTextFile(), if the user don't have write access, its not throwing any error. I can always see the success status.

Can someone faced similar issue, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As the Hadoop FileSystem class does not seem to have this functionality, you could use the Java [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class to accomplish this check.

```
File f = new File("path");
if(f.canWrite()) {
    // write access
}
```

Otherwise, if you end up needing to change the path permissions you can use:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
fs.setPermission(new Path(cleanFilePath), FsPermission permission)
```

Comment: I am not sure if i can use Java File class for this? Anyway i will check it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Awesome, I'm interested to know what the result is!